# Navigationlink question in Xcode 13.1 -- Blanks instead of links?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm stuck on why Navigationlink produces no links at all. Xcode compiles, but there's a blank for where the links to the new views are.  This particular view is View 3 from ContentView, so the structure is ContentView -> View 2 -> View 3 (trying to link to View 4).

```
struct MidnightView: View {

var hourItem: HoursItems

@State var showPreferencesView = false

@State var chosenVersion: Int = 0

@State var isPsalmsExpanded: Bool = false

@State var showLXX: Bool = false
   
var body: some View {
    ScrollView (.vertical) {
        VStack  (alignment: .center) {
            Group {
                Text (hourItem.hourDescription)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text ("Introduction to the \(hourItem.hourName)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .bold()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                ForEach (tenthenou, id: \.self) {
                    Text ("\($0)")
                    Text ("\(doxasi)")
                        .italic()
                }
            }
            .padding()
         NavigationView {
             
                List {
                    ForEach (midnightHours, id:\.id) {watch in
                        
                        NavigationLink ("The \(watch.watchName)", destination: MidnightWatchView (midnightItem: watch, chosenVersion: self.chosenVersion, isPsalmsExpanded: self.isPsalmsExpanded, showLXX: self.showLXX))
                    }
                }
                    
         }
        Group {
            Text ("Absolution of the \(hourItem.hourName)")
                .font(.headline)
            Text (absolutionTexts[(hourItem.hourName)] ?? " ")
            Divider()
            Text ("Conclusion of Every Hour")
                .font(.headline)
            Text (hourConclusion)
            Divider()
            Text (ourFather)
        }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle ("The Midnight Hour", displayMode: .automatic)
    .navigationBarItems (trailing: Button (action: {self.showPreferencesView.toggle()}) {Text (psalmVersions[chosenVersion])}
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showPreferencesView) {PreferencesView(showPreferencesView: self.$showPreferencesView, chosenVersion: self.$chosenVersion, isPsalmsExpanded: self.$isPsalmsExpanded, showLXX: self.$showLXX)})
}
```

}

Comment: Without a [mre] (yours has a lot of missing types making it impossible to compile), this is going to be challenging to debug. I will say that right off, it looks odd to have a `NavigationView` in the middle of a `ScrollView`. In general, you should only have *one* `NavigationView` at the top of your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the `NavigationLink` not appearing is probably due to the fact that you're including a `List` within a `ScrollView`. Because `List` is a scrolling component as well, the sizing gets messed up and the `List` ends up with a height of `0`. Remove the `List {` and corresponding `}` and your links should appear.

There are a number of other potential issues in your code (as I alluded to in my comment), including a `NavigationView` in the middle of a `ScrollView`. I'd remove that as well, as you *probably* have a `NavigationView` higher up in your view hierarchy already.

Comment: totally did the trick.  thanks!